# Using JavaScipt for calculating HMAC-SHA256 signature

Tags: javascript, cryptography, hmac

I need to calculate the HMAC-sha256 signature in JavaScript. I am using the following code.

```
crypto.createHmac('sha256','abc123').update('{"video-id":"212zpS6bjN77eixPUMUEjR", "exp-time": 1458396066}').digest('hex');
console.log( '1458396066' + '~'+ res);
```

The resulting hash I get is: `1458396066~d87d121117b46dc28ffec1117cd44cb114b32c1d7bfe5db30ebee7cb89221d3e`

This is not the hash that I am expecting. I have implemented code in PHP and Java which seems to work fine.

PHP Code

```
<?php

 $videoId = "212zpS6bjN77eixPUMUEjR";
 $sharedSecret = "abc123";

function generateToken($videoId, $sharedSecret, $lifeTime)
{
$expiryTime = "1458396066";
$data = sprintf("{\"video-id\":\"%s\", \"exp-time\": %s}" , $videoId, "1458396066");
$hash = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $data , hex2bin($sharedSecret) );
$token = sprintf ("%s~%s","1458396066" , $hash);
return $token;
}

$token = generateToken($videoId, $sharedSecret, 5);
echo $token;
?>
```

JAVA Code

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class VMProToken {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String videoID = "212zpS6bjN77eixPUMUEjR";
    final String sharedSecret = "abc123";

    try {
        final String token = generateToken(videoID, sharedSecret);
        System.out.println(token);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String generateToken(String videoId, String sharedSecret)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    final String HASH_PATTERN = "{\"video-id\":\"%s\", \"exp-time\": %s}";
    final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

    final String tokenCalcBase = String.format(HASH_PATTERN, videoId, 1458396066);
    System.out.println(tokenCalcBase);
    final Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
    final byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(sharedSecret);
    final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HASH_ALGORITHM);

    hmac.init(secretKey);
    final byte[] hmacBytes = hmac.doFinal(tokenCalcBase.getBytes());
    System.out.println(String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, hmacBytes)));
    final String hash = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, hmacBytes));

    return 1458396066 + "~" + hash;
}
}
```

The above two codes result in the correct answer which is

`1458396066~62dcbe0e20827245454280c51129a9f30d1122eaeafc5ce88f0fec527631f1b5`

Can somebody please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is processed as a hexadecimal encoded string in the PHP and Java code, but not in the NodeJS code. To do the same in the NodeJS code, replace `'abc123'` with `Buffer.from('abc123', 'hex')` in the `createHmac` call.